# How to moving pictures to the right using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am very new to javascript and trying to do something basic with 4 images.  I am attempting to get the all to move right and the one on the end move to the front. Could someone tell me if I am headed in the right direction?  Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
<html>


<head>
<title>Onclick Assignment</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

var moveButton = document.getElementByID("button");
moveButton.onclick = function moveImagesRight()
{
 var img1Src = document.getElementById("img1").src;
 var img2Src = document.getElementById("img2").src;
 var img3Src = document.getElementById("img3").src;
 var img4Src = document.getElementById("img4").src;

 document.getElementById("img1") = img2Src;
 document.getElementById("img2") = img3Src;
 document.getElementById("img3") = img4Src;
 document.getElementById("img4") = img1Src;

}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<table>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;">Image 1</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">Image 2</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">Image 3</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">Image 4</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td style="height: 200px;"><img id="img1" src="images/clover.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
    <td style="height: 200px;"><img id="img2" src="images/gold.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
    <td style="height: 200px;"><img id="img3" src="images/hat.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
    <td style="height: 200px;"><img id="img4" src="images/leprechaun.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Move Images..." id="button" onclick="moveImagesRight();"/>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: does this work when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do.  It seems you want to switch the src of each img.

```
function switchSrcs(){
    var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td"); // selects all cells!
    var finalSrc = cells[cells.length-1].firstChild.src; //get the src of the final image 
    for (var i = cells.length; i > 0; i--){ //this iterates backwards
        cells[i-1].firstChild.src = i != 1 ? cells[i-2].firstChild.src : finalSrc;
    };
};
```

The line in the for loop is a condensed if statement checking that we are not at the first element (which will happen last because we are iterating backwards).

It would be beneficial to set an id for the tr and then select all of the child cells (td) for that particular id.

Comment: Thank you fauxserious! This helped a lot.